# How do you make AWS SAM deploy use aws profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I need to have SAM deploy use a specific aws config profile. Where do you set that? This aws profile assumes a role needed for deploying.

Answer (score 20):

```
sam deploy --guided --profile some_role --region us-west-2
```

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same issue while dealing with multiple AWS CLI profiles. You first need to build the project with the following:

```
sam build --profile <name>
```

And then deploy with the following parameters:

```
sam deploy --profile <name> --guided
```

You will also notice that it will automatically add the custom profile inside the autogenerated `samconfig.toml` so that next time you don't need to specify the `--profile` flag when running `sam deploy`

```
version = 0.1
[default]
[default.deploy]
[default.deploy.parameters]
stack_name = "XXX"
s3_bucket = "XXX"
s3_prefix = "lb-api"
region = "us-east-1"
capabilities = "CAPABILITY_IAM"
parameter_overrides = "Stage=\"Staging\""
image_repositories = []
profile = "XX" <--------
```